# Move first 10 files from a folder to another

Tags: vbscript

I would like to know how I can move the first 10 files in folder to another folder? I have a folder which contains more than 50K files that need to be moved to another location for processing. I want to move 10 files at a time.

Please help to find a way using VBScript.

Comment: Define "first". The `FileSystemObject` in VBScript doesn't guarantee any order when iterating files.

Comment: Doesnt need any specific orders,just need to move 10 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need to move *any* 10 files from a folder, just maintain a file count as you iterate the `Files` collection of a `Folder` object.

For example:

```
intCount = 0
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

For Each objFile In objFSO.GetFolder("c:\path\to\your\files").Files
    objFile.Move "c:\new\path\"
    intCount = intCount + 1
    If intCount = 10 Then Exit For
Next
```

As I mentioned in the comments, there's no guarantee here which 10 files will get moved. Also of note, make sure to use a blackslash `\` at the end of the path you're moving the file to (`c:\new\path\`) so that it's treated as a folder and not a new file name.